# 'includes' method doesn't seem to work with 'where' in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Model I have:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :artist

  def self.default_scope
    includes :artist
  end

  def self.search query
    if query
      where "title LIKE :query OR artists.name LIKE :query", query: "%#{ query }%"
    else
      where nil
    end
  end

end
```

And in my controller:

```
def index
  @songs = Song.search(params[:search])
  respond_with(@songs)
end
```

When I search I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'artists.name' in 'where clause': SELECT  `songs`.* FROM `songs` WHERE (title LIKE '%my search%' OR artists.name LIKE '%my search%' OR albums.name LIKE '%my search%')
```

What am I doing wrong?, I thought the includes method would make the join automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations):

> Using `where` like this will only work when you pass it a Hash. For
>   SQL-fragments you need use `references` to force joined tables

You are correct that the `includes` method will make the join automatically, but **only** when a hash is used as the argument to `where`.

This will detect the query and join on `comments`:

```
Article.includes(:comments).where(comments: { visible: true })
```

This requires an explicit `references`:

```
Article.includes(:comments).where("comments.visible = true").references(:comments)
```

Without getting into whether `default_scope` is a good thing or not, you could get your code running with this:

```
def self.search(query)
  if query
    references(:artists).
      where("title LIKE :query OR artists.name LIKE :query", query: "%#{query}%")
  else
    where nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`includes` does not generate `join` sql so you cannot access other table columns. In fact, it is a very tricky method to use at all, normally it is better to use `preload` or `joins` - understanding differences will have a huge impact on your application performance. You need to use `join` here:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :artist

  default_scope { joins :artist }

  def self.search query
    if query
      where "title LIKE :query OR artists.name LIKE :query", query: "%#{ query }%"
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

Note however that using default_scope for joins or includes is not the cleanest way and will eventually backfire at you (learnt that the hard way) with performance penalties.

Comment: While I am implementing something similar to includes in php, I can see how consuming is to do something like that, especially that includes run each request separately