# Rails where syntax change from Rails 3 to 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, I have this code:

```
def self.active
      includes(configuration_slots: [:configuration])
        .where("configurations.is_active = 't'")
end
```

Is this not allowed anymore in Rails 3? Why not? What's the reason?

I have to write this now:

```
where(configurations: { is_active: true })
```

Comment: What makes you think that you can't write that any more? Did you get an error, a warning, or just see it in documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['includes' method doesn't seem to work with 'where' in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865823/includes-method-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-where-in-rails-4)